# How to get a better contrast on Windows taskbar buttons?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, ergonomics

I have two problems with the Windows taskbar buttons in Windows 7 (the taskbar is aligned to the left side of the screen):

1) There is almost no contrast between the focused window and other windows

2) There is a bad contrast between text and background

I am not visually handicapped, so I don't want to use the "High-Contrast" windows theme. I just want to have a better contrast for the mentioned problems on the Windows taskbar. Is this possible?

[image: ergonomics problem on Windows taskbar]

Comment: What happens if you select a darker background? That should increase the contrast.

Comment: Which background? The background of the desktop? That is already very dark.

Comment: Yes, I meant the desktop background. I can see the difference on mine with a dark desktop background but you're right, it's not very clear at all.